# Problems with formal series Z[[X]]

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can someone point out an error in the below "identity" considered as formal series :

$\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} x^ n = \sum_{n=1}^ \infty x^{-n} + \sum_{n=0}^ \infty x^n = \frac{x^{-1}}{1-x^ {-1}} + \frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{1-x} = 0$

I guess summing $\sum_{n=1}^ \infty x^{-n}$ as geometric series is fishy as the denominator goes to infinity,so could that be the problem?

Comment: $x^{-1}$ is not in $\Bbb Z[[X]]$.

Comment: thanks man i am getting delusional